# THREE.JS | GLSL How to split canvas texture to multiple planes

Tags: three.js, glsl, textures, crop, plane

I have a small demo, there I have multiple planes stacked together inside 1024x1024 area.
The task it to evenly split 1024x1024 animated canvas texture, so I would get the following result:

[image]

Not this:

[image]

So, I have somehow to pass to their shaders material which part from canvas texture I need to crop. And I don't know how to do it.

The current code is attached here.

The following answer is great, but I have to use glsl for these planes, so this solution could fit other tasks, not mine.

```js
    
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, glslMaterial, uniforms, canvas, ctx, markupTexture, t = 0.0;
  
inits();
    
function inits(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas")

    canvas.width = 1024 * 2;
    canvas.height = 1024 * 2;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    markupTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    //markupTexture.flipX = false;
    //markupTexture.flipY = false;
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0x080820, 2.0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5120 );
    camera.position.set(-200, 400, 400);
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var markupGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024, 1024, 64, 64);
    var markupPlane = new THREE.Mesh(markupGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, map: markupTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
    markupPlane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    markupPlane.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    //scene.add(markupPlane);
    
    var uniforms = {
        
        markup: { type: 't', value: markupTexture }
        
    };

    glslMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
        //side: new THREE.DoubleSide
        
    });
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane0";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(256, 0, -256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane1";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane2";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane3";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane4";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane5";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-256, 0, 256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane6";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane7";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane8";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane9";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    window.addEventListener( "resize", onWindowResize, false );
    
    animate();
    
}
    
function onWindowResize() {
    
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      
}

    
function animate() {
    
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 640, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 16.0;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 640, t - Math.PI / 8, t + Math.PI / 8, false);
    ctx.lineTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.fill();
    
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        
        scene.getObjectByName("plane" + i).material.uniforms.markup.needsUpdate = true;
        
    }
    //glslMaterial.uniforms.markup.needsUpdate = true;
    markupTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    
    t += 0.05;

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {

        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix *  vec4(position,1.0);

    }
    
</script>
    
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform sampler2D markup;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
    
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(markup, vUv);
        
    }
    
</script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a custom shader. You just need to set the texture coordinates for each plane.

Here's a function to scale and offset the texture coordinates

```
function offsetUVs(geometry, offU, offV, scaleU, scaleV) {
  const off = new THREE.Vector2(offU, offV);
  const scale = new THREE.Vector2(scaleU, scaleV);
  for(const uvs of geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]) {
    for (const uv of uvs) {
      uv.multiply(scale);
      uv.add(off);
    }
  }
}
```

If you set the scale to 0.25, 0.25 then one 16th of the texture will appear on that plane (as in if the texture was divided into a 4x4 grid)

The offset will move the texture where 1 is the full length of the texture, 0.5 is half the length, 0.25 is a quarter of the length

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, glslMaterial, uniforms, canvas, ctx, markupTexture, t = 0.0;
  
inits();
    
function inits(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas")

    canvas.width = 1024 * 2;
    canvas.height = 1024 * 2;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    markupTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    //markupTexture.flipX = false;
    //markupTexture.flipY = false;
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0x080820, 2.0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5120 );
    camera.position.set(-200, 400, 400);
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var markupGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024, 1024, 64, 64);
    var markupPlane = new THREE.Mesh(markupGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, map: markupTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
    markupPlane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    markupPlane.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    //scene.add(markupPlane);
    

    /*glslMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
        //side: new THREE.DoubleSide
        
    });
    */
    const simple = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, map: markupTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane0";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(256, 0, -256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane1";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane2";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane3";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.75, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane4";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane5";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-256, 0, 256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane6";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane7";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane8";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.0, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, simple);
    plane.name = "plane9";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    window.addEventListener( "resize", onWindowResize, false );
    
    animate();
    
}

function offsetUVs(geometry, offU, offV, scaleU, scaleV) {
  const off = new THREE.Vector2(offU, offV);
  const scale = new THREE.Vector2(scaleU, scaleV);
  for(const uvs of geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]) {
    for (const uv of uvs) {
      uv.multiply(scale);
      uv.add(off);
    }
  }
}
    
function onWindowResize() {
    
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      
}

    
function animate() {
    
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 16.0;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, t - Math.PI / 8, t + Math.PI / 8, false);
    ctx.lineTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.fill();
    markupTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    
    t += 0.05;

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Ps: I made the circle bigger so it touched all the planes otherwise 2 corners were solid yellow so it was hard to see if they were correct.

See [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-geometry.html) as a reference for the structure of geometry

The same solution will work just fine with your custom shader as well

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, glslMaterial, uniforms, canvas, ctx, markupTexture, t = 0.0;
  
inits();
    
function inits(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas")

    canvas.width = 1024 * 2;
    canvas.height = 1024 * 2;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    markupTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    //markupTexture.flipX = false;
    //markupTexture.flipY = false;
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0x080820, 2.0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5120 );
    camera.position.set(-200, 400, 400);
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var markupGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024, 1024, 64, 64);
    var markupPlane = new THREE.Mesh(markupGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, map: markupTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
    markupPlane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    markupPlane.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    //scene.add(markupPlane);
    
    var uniforms = {
        
        markup: { type: 't', value: markupTexture }
        
    };

    glslMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        
        uniforms: uniforms,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
        //side: new THREE.DoubleSide
        
    });
    
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane0";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(256, 0, -256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane1";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane2";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.5, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane3";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.75, 0, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane4";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane5";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-256, 0, 256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane6";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane7";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane8";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    offsetUVs(geometry, 0.0, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, glslMaterial);
    plane.name = "plane9";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    window.addEventListener( "resize", onWindowResize, false );
    
    animate();
    
}

function offsetUVs(geometry, offU, offV, scaleU, scaleV) {
  const off = new THREE.Vector2(offU, offV);
  const scale = new THREE.Vector2(scaleU, scaleV);
  for(const uvs of geometry.faceVertexUvs[0]) {
    for (const uv of uvs) {
      uv.multiply(scale);
      uv.add(off);
    }
  }
}
    
function onWindowResize() {
    
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      
}

    
function animate() {
    
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 16.0;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, t - Math.PI / 8, t + Math.PI / 8, false);
    ctx.lineTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.fill();
    markupTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    
    t += 0.05;

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {

        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix *  vec4(position,1.0);

    }
    
</script>
    
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform sampler2D markup;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
    
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(markup, vUv);
        
    }
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

you can also do the same uv manipulation in the shader but you'll need to create a new material for each plane so you can pass in a different offset and scale for each one.

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, glslMaterial, uniforms, canvas, ctx, markupTexture, t = 0.0;
  
inits();
    
function inits(){

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas")

    canvas.width = 1024 * 2;
    canvas.height = 1024 * 2;

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    markupTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
    //markupTexture.flipX = false;
    //markupTexture.flipY = false;
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0x080820, 2.0 );
    scene.add( light );
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5120 );
    camera.position.set(-200, 400, 400);
    
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    
    var markupGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1024, 1024, 64, 64);
    var markupPlane = new THREE.Mesh(markupGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, map: markupTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
    markupPlane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    markupPlane.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    //scene.add(markupPlane);
    
    function createMaterial(offX, offY, scaleX, scaleY) {
      var uniforms = {
          uvOffset: { value: new THREE.Vector2(offX, offY) },
          uvScale: { value: new THREE.Vector2(scaleX, scaleY) },
          markup: { type: 't', value: markupTexture }

      };

      return new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

          uniforms: uniforms,
          vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
          fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
          //side: new THREE.DoubleSide

      });
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    plane.name = "plane0";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(256, 0, -256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane1";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane2";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.5, 0, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane3";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(128, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.75, 0, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane4";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(384, 0, 384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(512, 512, 64, 64);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5));
    plane.name = "plane5";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-256, 0, 256)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane6";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane7";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -128)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane8";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-128, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(256, 256, 32, 32);
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, createMaterial(0.0, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25));
    plane.name = "plane9";
    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    plane.position.set(-384, 0, -384)
    scene.add(plane);
    
    window.addEventListener( "resize", onWindowResize, false );
    
    animate();
    
}
    
function onWindowResize() {
    
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
      
}

    
function animate() {
    
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.lineWidth = 16.0;
    ctx.stroke();
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.arc(1024, 1024, 940, t - Math.PI / 8, t + Math.PI / 8, false);
    ctx.lineTo(1024, 1024);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF00FF";
    ctx.fill();
    
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    markupTexture.needsUpdate = true;
    
    t += 0.05;

}
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {

        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix *  vec4(position,1.0);

    }
    
</script>
    
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform sampler2D markup;
    uniform vec2 uvOffset;
    uniform vec2 uvScale;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
    
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(markup, vUv * uvScale + uvOffset);
        
    }
</script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I HAVE to use shader for planes for other task.

Comment: The solution will still work as is with your custom shader. Put you shader back in and it will work just fine. My only point was for what you showed you don't need the custom shader to achieve the result you asked for.